How to prioritize synchronization mechanisms working on shared data in Android?
I have an Android application with three different synchronization mechanisms that operate independently, each using its own CoroutineScope. All these synchronizations depend on the same type of data (e.g., inventory data) stored in a database. I currently use DataStore for data storage but plan to migrate to Room due to performance issues with large datasets.
Here is the problem:
Each synchronization mechanism processes the data differently (e.g., downloading from an API, local filtering, mapping, etc.).
The second synchronization mechanism, which fetches the latest data from an API, should have the highest priority. This means it should always ensure its data updates are not overwritten by other synchronization mechanisms working on outdated data.
Here’s an example scenario:
00:01: The second synchronization starts downloading the latest data from the API and start saving process to the local database.
00:02: The first synchronization starts processing data fetched from the local database, which is still the old data.
00:03: The second synchronization finishes, saving the newest data to the database.
00:04: The first synchronization finishes processing and overwrites the database with the outdated data.
At the end, I end up with outdated data in the database because the first synchronization overwrites the newer data saved by the second synchronization.
To simplify:
simple: 
-> fetch entire inventory (1st synchro) 
-> fetch stocks (2nd synchro) with creating instance with local DB(OLD data) to process
-> inventory is saved to local DB( 1st synchro) 
-> inventory is saved to local DB (2nd synchro) will old data. 
Last save is with old data, effect is the same as I don't download any new entire inventory with 1st synchro

My Questions:
How can I prioritize the second synchronization mechanism so that no other synchronization processes outdated data or overwrites its updates?
Is there an efficient way to handle this scenario?
Are there recommended patterns or best practices in Android (e.g., using Mutex, shared flags, or queues) to handle synchronization of independent mechanisms accessing shared data?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.

I fail to see the issue. I understand that you want to update your local data by calling an API over the network. But I do not understand what the other "synchronization" process does. It "starts processing data fetched from the local database and overwrites the database". What does that mean? Does it read the data in question, or does it write the data? It surely won't just write the same data back. And when it is just a calculation, then the result would (should) end up in another table. In no scenario I can picture how that woud conflict with the API job. Please [edit] and clarify.

One of the synchronization doesn't download inventory, it downloads only stocks and uses local database to work with. I see the possibility that one process could be started as downloading entire inventory, but local database won't be updated yet, then during it fetches entire inventory second synchro starts update stocks, but it uses local database, which NOW IMPORTANT could create instance of old data then it will process updating stocks during this time first synchro uses SAVETOLOCALDB and second later after updating local stocks with old data it will update the database with OLD DATA

I don't see any issues with my explanation I see it simple:
-> fetch entire inventory (1st synchro)
-> fetch stocks (2nd synchro) with creating instance  with local DB(OLD data) to process
-> inventory is saved to local DB( 1st synchro)
-> inventory is saved to local DB (2nd synchro) will old data.
Last save is with old data, effect is the same as I don't download any new entire inventory with 1st synchro
I don't understand your misunderstandings what is difference between (2nd synchronization depend only on local database) or 2nd synchronization updates only stocks. This is the same

It could be rare to occur, but still my process of downloading entire inventory is rare it's like once a week. Where stock are updated every 3-5min

Sorry, I still don't understand what the issue is. Please [edit] your question to provide a [mre] that demonstrates how the different data flows are and how an inconsistency can arise.

Perhaps consider using a temporary/working table or set of tables for the OLD data. These could be emptied after they are no longer needed in readiness for the next run and then populated as the initial step of the run thus separating the two sets of data (where required).

You should use an orchestrator CoroutineScope with async and await to get new inventories at first, then let other synchronizer continue their work with new data.
I assume you need something like this:
val sync1 = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)
val sync2 = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)

viewModelScope.launch {
    val inventory = sync1.async {
        fetchInventory()
    }.await() // Wait to have new data
    sync1.launch {
        saveInventory(inventory)
    }
    sync2.launch {
        val stocks = fetchStock(inventory)
        saveStock(stocks)
    }
}

In this example, the viewModelScope is the orchestrator but you can replace it with any CoroutineScope is needed. The following screenshot, shows the importance of await which causes the orchestrator waits until new inventories fetch.

